# Finding the indexes of the smallest 3 elements in a subsetted vector

Tags: r, vector

I have the following vector `a`:

```
a<-c(100, 84, 126, 336, 544, 0, 2176)
```

I want to subset `a` using the following index vector `b:

```
b<-c(1,2,4,5,7)
```

In this case, the subset would be:

```
a[b]=c(100,84,336,544,3276)
```

From this subset of `a` I want to take the smallest three numbers. I then want to know what indexes of `a` these smallest three numbers are.

The smallest 3 numbers in this subset would be:

```
c(84,100,336)
```

So the indexes of these numbers in `a` would be:

```
result<-c(2,1,4)
```

How can I get to this final `result`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If efficiency is not important:

```
match(sort(a[b])[1:3], a)
# [1] 2 1 4
```

A bit faster:

```
match(sort(a[b], partial = 1:3)[1:3], a)
```

A bit cleaner:

```
intersect(order(a), b)[1:3]
```